# Babel Transpiler failing to run with Nodemon

Tags: node.js, npm, babeljs, nodemon

*Issue:*

Unable to use Babel Transpiler with Nodemon

*Details:*

In package.json I have:

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "nodemon --exec babel-node --presets=es2015 -- src/app.js"
},


"dependencies": {
   "nodemon": "^1.18.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/cli": "^7.1.2",
  "@babel/core": "^7.1.2",
  "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
  "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
  "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0"
}
```

When I run `npm start` My understanding is that nodemon should kick on save and run the babel transpiler; however, I get the following in the terminal.

> Error: Requires Babel "^7.0.0-0", but was loaded with "6.26.3". If you are sure you have a compatible version of @babel/core, it is likely that something in your build process is loading the wrong version. Inspect the stack trace of this error to look for the first entry that doesn't mention "@babel/core" or "babel-core" to see what is calling Babel.

I thought this was caused by the `babel-cli` dependency of 6.26 but when I remove that it squawks:

`[nodemon] failed to start process, "babel-node" exec not found`

Searching through the good ol' google machine I see some other people with more complicated setups and their solutions seem to fly over the top of my head.

*Recreation Steps:*

1. Run `npm init -y` & `npm i nodemon`
2. Follow instructions here: https://babeljs.io/setup#installation (nodemon) selected
3. Run `npm install @babel/core --save-dev` as I was warned that the core was not installed.
4. Run `npm start`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When running Babel with nodemon you need to include these packages.

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/cli": "^7.1.2",
  "@babel/core": "^7.1.2",
  "@babel/polyfill": "^7.0.0",
  "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
  "@babel/node": "^7.0.0",
  "nodemon": "^1.18.4"
}
```

Then adjust your npm run script to:

`"start": "nodemon app/index.js --exec babel-node app/index.js"`

Thanks to the Babel Slack channel for this answer!

Comment: After searching through multiple github issues and thread here, this is the only solution that worked. In my case After pasting this, I had to delete package-lock.json file and node modules folder and run npm install again to delete all traces of previous node module files.

Comment: As of Babel 7.4.0, `@babel/polyfill` package has been deprecated in favor of directly including `core-js/stable` 
via https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill